# Как перевести значения UNIXTIMESTAMP в дату?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, unixtimestamp

Есть DataFrame который содержит дату в `UNIXTIMESTAMP`.

Как перевести значение, если они превышают допустимое значение стандартных функций Pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATETIME': [96028070400000,10967555200000,1567555200000,-1167555200000]})
```

Пробовал to_datetime, падает с ошибкой:

```
df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], unit='ms')
```

Пробовал to_timedelta, неправильно переводит первый элемент:

```
df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DATETIME'], unit='ms') + pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')
```

Должно получится примерно так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATETIME': [5013-01-04,2317-07-20,2019-09-04,1933-01-01]})
```

Comment: а почему у вас получаются такие значения, которые "ревышают допустимое значение стандартных функций pandas"?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits

Comment: Ну вот такие значения пришли

Comment: @meyera3489, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Возможно у вас UNIXTIMESTAMP в микросекундах?

```
In [155]: pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], unit='us')
Out[155]:
0   1973-01-16 10:27:50.400
1   1970-05-07 22:32:35.200
2   1970-01-19 03:25:55.200
3   1969-12-18 11:40:44.800
Name: DATETIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

или в наносекундах:

```
In [160]: pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'], unit='ns')
Out[160]:
0   1970-01-02 02:40:28.070400
1   1970-01-01 03:02:47.555200
2   1970-01-01 00:26:07.555200
3   1969-12-31 23:40:32.444800
Name: DATETIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Тут проблема в том что именно дату переводит неверную, unit='us', unit='ns' не причем. Выше написал как примерно должно получится(отсчет даты также с 1970-01-01), т.е полученные выходные значение не должны ограничиваться, не 1970 (может быть 1200 год), не 2300 (может быть 3650 год), если это конечно возможно

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться типом данных [period[D]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html):

```
df["date"] = (df["DATETIME"]
              .div(1000)
              .apply(lambda x: pd.Period(DT.utcfromtimestamp(x)
                                           .strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))))
```

Результат:

```
In [189]: df
Out[189]:
         DATETIME        date
0  96028070400000  5013-01-04
1  10967555200000  2317-07-20
2   1567555200000  2019-09-04
3  -1167555200000  1933-01-01
```

Арифметика с датами работает с этим типом данных:

```
In [190]: df["date"] + pd.offsets.Day(1)
Out[190]:
0    5013-01-05
1    2317-07-21
2    2019-09-05
3    1933-01-02
Name: date, dtype: period[D]

In [191]: df.dtypes
Out[191]:
DATETIME        int64
date        period[D]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Может я чего не понимаю, но с теме же значениями ваша конструкция выдает Invalid argument. `df["DATE"] = (df["DATETIME"].div(1000).apply(lambda x: pd.Period(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))))`

Comment: @meyera3489, какая у вас версия Pandas?

Comment: pandas == 1.2.4  Но при этом если значения во frame меньше то конструкция работает

Comment: @meyera3489, у меня Pandas 1.2.3 и весь вывод (`output`) в данном ответе - это результат запуска на моей машине. Попробуйте запускать по частям, чтобы понять в каком месте выдает ошибку...